# Why isn't the Gravity Machine ever used as a weapon?

Tags: dragon-ball, artificial-gravity

In Dragon Ball, the Z Fighters train under high artificial gravity to be extremely strong under normal gravity. I don't recall the Gravity Machine having an upper limit to its effect, though, and there have been a few cases where the gravity has been too strong for the person training. Is there a reason the Z Fighters haven't used it as a weapon, say by cranking it up beyond what the enemy is able to withstand? Or have they and it slipped my memory?

I get that the point of Dragon Ball, visually, is fighting and training sequences, but it just seems to me that it would be easier and more resource-efficient to use the Gravity Machine as a weapon than putting the effort towards training under the high gravity and then fighting in person.

Comment: I don't think we see a character ever try to destroy a high-gravity machine; Goku uses it to train, but if he had wanted to, I suspect he could have fired energy straight down at the machine itself if he actually wanted to escape it...this is a show about planet-destroying aliens after all. Though, it's been awhile since I've watched DBZ

Comment: it would make no difference, kid trunks trains in the gravity chamber at one stage and is struggling to walk, he then turns SSJ and has no problem moving around. So ones power can offset the gravity if the Z fighters ever needed to try this their opponent would be so much more powerful than them that they themselves couldn't move in the gravity

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your theory is that Goku get exponentially stronger. So let's say `x` represents Goku at the start of DBZ. For argument's sake, this is how his power progresses

1. Goku vs Vegeta. Goku becomes `x^2` during the fight
2. Goku vs Freeza. Goku becomes `x^4` during the fight
3. Goku vs Cell. Goku becomes `x^8` during the fight

DBZ is an over-the-top fighting series. Goku uses this to train before Freeza (#2). He struggles greatly, especially when the storm in space causes the system to malfunction. He ultimately defeats Freeza so it's safe to say he's much stronger by the end of the arc. That's the only time we see him struggle with it. But we have a solid benchmark here. Trunks handily defeats a rebuilt Freeza, but loses to Cell. Goku loses to Cell as well, but he's definitely stronger by the end.

It's pretty safe to say that Cell(final form) would probably laugh it off. As such it would be moot to try from that point on in the series.

---

Dragonball Super more or less confirms this. We see Goku unable to move when the gravity machine goes to 100 in DBZ, but in this clip from DBS, we see Vegeta moving freely in 150.

The [DB Wikia page](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Gravity_Machine) also notes

> In the Trunks Saga, an upgraded version of the machine is created to help train Vegeta. According to the Daizenshuu, this more powerful version can go up to 300 times Earth's gravity. It is destroyed in the same Saga, during training. However it is subsequently rebuilt and Vegeta later increases the forces to over 400 times Earths gravity.

Answer (score -2):

The Gravity Device was inside a space ship.  I imagine it would be a little weird to be in the middle of a fight and stop and be like 'Hey, lets take this fight over there inside that ship.'  Beyond that I would have to agree with @Machavity that after a certain power level that it would be an insignificant annoyance at best.  In the later episodes of DBZ I can't recall them continuing to use the ship for that purpose anymore, signifying that it would seem to have an upper limit that makes it no longer useful or they just out grew it.